# Connect Windows Form Client With Tcp Server on Asp.Net Mvc Web

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tcp, router

I am working on client, server project according to this project the client wait for the server to come online and if the server is online connect with it and then wait for commands to act on.

I would like to implement server on **Web** so that the Dns ip can be resolve easily into ip address using

```
IPHostEntry hostEntry;

 hostEntry= Dns.GetHostEntry(host);

//you might get more than one ip for a hostname since 
//DNS supports more than one record

 if (hostEntry.AddressList.Length > 0)
  {
  var ip = hostEntry.AddressList[0];
  Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, 
    ProtocolType.IP);
  s.Connect(ip, 80);
   }
```

But Here are some issue when connecting client with server on different networking scenario. That's why I would like to shift the server on web application because a Url is accessible by all in any networking scenario.

**Issue When Implementing on Windows Application(Form)**

1. > The client program when run under the router ([Infrastructure mode](https://www.lifewire.com/infrastructure-mode-in-wireless-networking-816539)) cannot be able to connect with server if server using dynamic IP.
2. > Have to Port Forwarding on client side.

Please **suggest** me any method (if exist) to make connection between client/server without having these issues.

Comment: Dynamic IP just means the IP will change periodically but the name will always be the same.  So using host = Dns.GetHostName() will always get your code to  work.  Port Forwarding is needed to get through firewalls when certain port numbers are blocked.  You do not need to port forward if you use a port number that is not blocked.  Usually well known port numbers below 1000 are blocked so use a port number above 1000.  I usually use numbers above 10000.  So 80 is probably blocked so use different port numbers.

Comment: but sir I cannot listen on port 80 because it may be used by another program.

Comment: Port 80 is the standard port number for a webpage and often more than one webpage is operating simultaneously.  The is a source port number and a destination port number using a different source port number allows more than one application to use destination port number 80.

Comment: but this not solve my problem ,i just want to ask if there is a method to implement tcp server on web ? or not

Comment: A web uses TCP for transport layer.  There is a lot of work to implement you own TCP web service.   That is why there are libraries that already do the work.